# How to specify a conforming class for a protocol in Swift

Tags: swift

I wonder is that possible to create a protocol, in which its method refer to a type for the conforming class

**UHSyncObjectProtocol Protocol**

```
protocol UHSyncObjectProtocol: class {
     func sync(completionBlock: ((UHSyncObjectProtocol) -> Void)?)
     // ideally, I want to refer to the conforming class instead of UHSyncObjectProtocol
}
```

**User Profile Class**

```
class UHUserProfile: UHSyncObjectProtocol {
     func sync(completionBlock: ((UHUserProfile) -> Void)?) {
        // do something
        completionBlock?(self)
     }
}
```

**User Account Class**

```
class UHUserAccount: UHSyncObjectProtocol {
     func sync(completionBlock: ((UHUserAccount) -> Void)?) {
        // do something
        completionBlock?(self)
     }
}
```

I'm not sure it's possible or not.

Comment: You could use generics, but your first block of code is probably the best; Within the completion handler you can easily downcast from `UHSyncObjectProtocol` to the specific object type.

Comment: Yes, the generics may be better in my case, so that I don't have to downcast it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use generics to achieve that

Here is example

```
protocol UHSyncObjectProtocol: class {
    associatedtype T

    func sync(completionBlock: ((T) -> Void)?)
    // ideally, I want to refer to the conforming class instead of UHSyncObjectProtocol
}

class UHUserProfile: UHSyncObjectProtocol {
    func sync(completionBlock: ((UHUserProfile) -> Void)?) {
        // do something
        completionBlock?(self)
    }
}

class UHUserAccount: UHSyncObjectProtocol {
    func sync(completionBlock: ((UHUserAccount) -> Void)?) {
        // do something
        completionBlock?(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot protocol in Swift allow generic, thanks. This is what I'm looking for.